# How do I debug an AngularJS app in Visual Studio 2013 using Grunt?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

I am currently trying to debug an AngularJS app I'm writing using Visual Studio 2013. 
I have the recently released [Node.js Tools](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com) installed.

The app has been scaffolded using [Yeoman/Bower/Grunt](http://yeoman.io) and uses the commandline `grunt serve` command to package and start the localhost webserver.

How do I enable debugging from Visual Studio 2013?  Do I have to attach to process, or can I hook it up to the trusty F5 in vs2013, or is it even possible at all?

Comment: So for now I'm reverting to using Jetbrains Webstorm which debugs fine under windows.  Still interested in using VS2013 if possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Visual Studio extension which enables Grunt integration:

- [Grunt Launcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff)

It adds a right click menu with options to launch Grunt, Gulp and Bower commands. When right clicking on a gruntfile you will see a new submenu listing all your options.

There is also an Angular.js template:

- [Angular.js SPA Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83)

There are also more advanced solutions:

- [Building with nodeJS Tools for Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2014/05/21/building-with-node-js-tools-for-visual-studio.aspx)
- [ASP.net SPA Solution Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/359f4304-57d7-4178-9cab-165e2090dce2)
- [KarmaVs](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/02f47876-0e7a-4f6c-93f8-1af5d5189225)
- [How Can I Benefit from Grunt for my Visual Studio Based Web Development](http://www.joeriks.com/2013/08/06/can-i-benefit-from-grunt-for-my-visual-studio-based-web-development/)
- [Grunt your ASP.net Builds](http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/12/30/grunt-your-asp-net-builds/)
- [Creating a Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh768146.aspx)

Comment: Paul, thanks for the reply. Have you managed to get debug to work using the grunt launcher? When Webstorm debugs into the js it sets up the debug server on a port and then listens for it: eg: runnerw.exe "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=1878   This working debug server/listener combo is the bit we're missing on Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I haven't. It looks like the remote debugging with F5 support is available as part of the [NTVS](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNodejsToolsForVisualStudio.aspx) project.

Comment: Good spot... can't beat some good Hanselman instructions.  I'll see if I can get it working again.

Comment: Quick note to say the recent HackSummit presentation by Mr Hansleman showed some very impressive features coming down the pipe in Visual Studio backed by Roslyn.  It won't be long before seamless debugging will be with us.